# Find declaration of completionHandler

Tags: swift, closures, swift2, alamofire

I want to debug a SSL problem in the Swift 2.0 Alamofire library. I'm using a custom Alamofire Manager with a custom ServerTrustPolicy set-up like this:

```
static let manager: Manager = {
    let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
        "localhost": .PinCertificates(
            certificates: ServerTrustPolicy.certificatesInBundle(),
            validateCertificateChain: false,
            validateHost: false
        )
//        "localhost": .DisableEvaluation
    ]

    let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = Alamofire.Manager.defaultHTTPHeaders

   return Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configuration,
    serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies))
}()
```

I tried both, `.PinCertificates` and `.DisableEvaluation`. Both threw me the same error

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made."
UserInfo={
  NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=<SecTrustRef: 0x60c00004d980>,
  NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?,
  _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, 
  _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802, 
  NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey=<CFArray 0x6060001498a0 [0x10bb3c7b0]>{
    type = immutable, count = 1, values = (
     0 : <cert(0x61600006ed80) s: localhost i: localhost>
    )}, 
   NSUnderlyingError=0x6040000ad750 {
     Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)"
     UserInfo={
       _kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, 
       kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust=<SecTrustRef: 0x60c00004d980>,
       _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9802,
       _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3,
       _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802,
       kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates=<CFArray 0x6060001498a0 [0x10bb3c7b0]>{
         type = immutable, count = 1, values = (
           0 : <cert(0x61600006ed80) s: localhost i: localhost>
         )}
     }
   },
   NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.,
   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://localhost:3000/auth/requestToken?auth_appId=d018ccd505db2cb1d5aacabb03fc2f3a,
   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://localhost:3000/auth/requestToken?auth_appId=d018ccd505db2cb1d5aacabb03fc2f3a,
   NSErrorClientCertificateStateKey=0
}
```

I tried to do the request using curl which works just fine

```
curl --cacert ./ca.pem https://localhost:3000
```

I narrowed it down to a single method from where a completionHandler is beeing called. Until the closure gets called everything is fine so I want to know what this completionHandler actually does.

```
public func URLSession(
    session: NSURLSession,
    didReceiveChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge,
    completionHandler: ((NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential?) -> Void))
{
    // some other stuff but
    // everything fine so far

    completionHandler(disposition, credential)
}
```

I think the `URLSession` method gets called from a dispatch queue or something like that.

So my question: How can I find the closure that is passed as the `completionHandler` argument to the `URLSession` method?

Comment: you should be able to step-into the closure. or just check where is this method get called.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Are you using a custom `ServerTrustPolicy`? Alamofire uses Apple's default server trust evaluation by default. If you could be a bit more specific, it would be much easier to help.

Comment: I updated my question with more information :)

Answer (score 0):

**-** I assume your problem here is not this particular method but how `completionHandler` works in `Swift`.

**-** Here the `completionHandler` in a `closure` which in-turn works as `Callback`.

**-** In `Swift` Callbacks are handled by `closure` and `delegates`.

**-** Let me clear the confusion with a small example,

**Problem:**

Assume I have a method to call, so I will call that method and on getting the response back I need to display the result on screen or console.

**Solution:**

- **Method to be called:**

`internal func sumUp(valOne: Int, valTwo: Int, completionHandler: (sum: Int)-> Void)
 {
    let add = valOne + valTwo
    completionHandler(sum: add)
 }`

- **Calling code:**

`sumUp{`

```
      (sum) -> Void in
       print(sum) // OR print it in display
```

`}`

**-** Calling the method `sumUp` will do the work of summing up two Integers, and then **return the sum** into `completionHandler` exposing it to the `caller`.